# Is editing Info.plist and RunScript possible programmatically and dynamically?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, info.plist, run-script

In our native iOS app we use Crashlytics for logging Crashes.

We need a way to differentiate crash logs between TestFlight and live users, our bundle ID and distribution profiles are the same for TestFilght and live users, that is the final build is created using production profile, and submitted to Apple for TestFlight, and then advanced directly to App Store, once TestFlight is successful.

One way to separate out the crashes is, Crashlytics provides API key which is added in info.plist, this API key is unique for every crashlytics account, so if we have two different accounts in crashlytics and use one account API key for live users and other for testflight by this we can achieve this. Below is how we have planned to do this -

we add a user setting (under Settings), that can help us differentiate sessions between TestFlight users v/s live users? This will require us to create another API key under Crashlytics. So, we can use one for TestFlight users, and another one for live users, which will be our default setting.

Example:
- Settings > Our app > Advanced > Tester (True/False)

By default, we can leave the toggle switch to false for “Tester” users, so that it defaults to a live user.
However, for our testing, we can possibly have our internal testes turn this setting on, so that we can check the setting at app launch, and can log the crashes/sessions under a different API key.

This is the reason why I wanted to know is editing Info.plist and RunScript possible programmatically and dynamically based on a condition?